# gitでディレクトリのシンボリックリンクを管理するときの扱いについて

Tags: git

Gitでシンボリックリンクをコミットできるようですが、そうした場合、そのディレクトリの中身もすべてgitにより管理されるのでしょうか。それとも、ディレクトリの中身は管理されずに、ディレクトリだけが何らかの形で管理されるようになるのでしょうか。
そのディレクトリには割りと大きめのファイルが入っているのでできれば、ディレクトリの中身をgitで管理したくないです。
この場合.gitignoreでそのシンボリックリンクのはられたディレクトリを除外するしかないのでしょうか。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links にもありますが、「文字列ファイルとしての symlink」が登録されます。 symlink があろうとなかあろうと。 (回答としてこれを記述したつもりでしたが、勝手にコメントになっていてびっくりしてます。)

Comment: ということはディレクトリ以下のファイルは追加されないということでしょうか。

Comment: そういうことだったはずです。。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

（一度、回答を書いたのですが、上のコメントの通り、勝手に自動変換されていました。未回答なのもあれなので、書き直しています。）

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links

にもありますが、 symlink は、 git 上ではただのファイルとして取り扱われます。（ symlink の実体は、 link の情報が書かれたテキストファイル（のようなもの？実際のところはよく知らないです）ですが、それがそのまま登録されます。)